# Can't use jquery "on click" with bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble using the bootstrap carousel and having clickable elements.  This is some code pulled from my source.  How can I have both the original and the revision clickable?

Here is a js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/v9ec3/204/

Here is my code

```
#myCarousel.carousel.slide{id: original.id}
      .carousel-inner
        - if count == 1
          .item
            .col-lg-6.col-xs-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6{id: "original-link", "data-target" => ".original_#{post.id}", "data-toggle" => "modal"}
              .text-center
                %b
                  ORIGINAL
                %a
                %br
                #border
                  = image_tag original.snapshot
            - count += 1
        - completed_drafts.each do |post|
          - if count == 2
            .item.active 
              .col-lg-6.col-xs-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6{id: ".revision_#{post.id}", class: "link",  "data-toggle" => "modal", :category => post}
                .text-center
                  %b
                    REVISED
                %a

                #border
                  = image_tag post.snapshot

            - count += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you use clone() to add new elements to the DOM. So you need to use a live event, so new qualifying elements are registered as well.

I guess something like

```
$(".carousel-inner").on("click", ".link", function({ 
    alert("this works!");
  }));
```

would work.